# How to turn off OpenLayers 4 smooth zooming

Tags: openlayers, zoom

After upgrading from OpenLayers3 to OpenLayers4, the zooming has changed. Now the user can zoom to zoomlevels between integers. It does not look okay for some raster layers.

Good (same as source raster map):

### [image: source raster map]

Little bit zoomed by OpenLayers (looks blurred):

### [image]

How can I turn off this zoom option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `constrainResolution` option on `ol.interaction.PinchZoom`
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_PinchZoom.html

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({}).extend([
        new ol.interaction.PinchZoom({
            constrainResolution: true
        })
    ]),
    .....
});
```

If you want to set for `mouseWheelZoom`, just change `ol.interaction.PinchZoom` to `ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom`.
plus, `zoomDuration: 0` makes it no animation.